# Detect when specific program program has closed with C#

Tags: java, c#, process

I have two different .jar programs running on the same machine. I want to be able to detect when one of them has been closed, or is no longer running.

This issue that I am having is, when running this code:

```
  var allProc = Process.GetProcesses();
  foreach (var p in allProc)

  comboBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
  comboBox1.Sorted = true;
```

It only shows a single instance of Java running, and not only that it doesn't show either of the process names.

The program I want to monitor uses a lot of RAM, so I thought about monitoring RAM usage and doing what I need when it drops below a certain level, but to me that sounds like a hacky way of doing it and other factors could effect it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to get the *Process Id* for the parent process you're looking for.

From there you can then use WMI through the (`System.Management`) namespace to search for the child processes:

```
Process[] javaProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("somejavaapp.exe");
foreach (Process proc in javaProcesses)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    "SELECT * " +
    "FROM Win32_Process " +
    "WHERE ParentProcessId=" + proc.Id);

    ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

    // Choose what to do with the child processes.
    foreach (var childProcess in collection)
    {
        var childProcessId = (UInt32)childProcess["ProcessId"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Issue a while ago, the best Solution for me was to run the java Programm as child.

Example

```
  server = new Process();
  server.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
  server.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xmx4000M -jar forge.jar nogui";
  server.Start();
```

Then Simply

```
  status = server.HasExited;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line tool that comes with the JDK called [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html). 
`jps -v` shows all the arguments you have passed to java. It provides the following output:

`lvmid [ [ classname | JARfilename | "Unknown"] [ arg* ] [ jvmarg* ] ]`

You can call jps from c# and then read the output.